# another jquery find next class not sibling for slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

All `.setupData` are hidden by default.

When I click on a `.setupTitle` class , I want its immediate (next in DOM) `.setupData` to toggle.

I've tried may variations of

```
$(".setupTitle").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".setupBlock").next(".setupData").slideToggle();
});
```

but no dice.

```
<div class="setupBlock">
    <div class="setupTitle">
        consignees <img src="img/open.png" class="openArrow"">
    </div>
    <div id="consigneeDiv" class="setupData">
            consignees
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>  

<div class="setupBlock">
    <div class="setupTitle">
        locations <img src="img/open.png" class="openArrow"">
    </div>
    <div id="locaDiv" class="setupData">
        locations
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>  

<div class="setupBlock">
    <div class="setupTitle">
        users <img src="img/open.png" class="openArrow"">
    </div>
    <div id="usersDiv" class="setupData">
            users
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>  

<div class="setupBlock">
    <div class="setupTitle">
        next numbers <img src="img/open.png" class="openArrow"">
    </div>
    <div id="nnDiv" class="setupData">
            next numbers
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.setupTitle` is a sibling of `.setupData`, you can call:

```
 $(".setupTitle").click(function(){

    $(this).siblings(".setupData").slideToggle();

  });
```

or if you prefer to use `.next()` you can use:

```
 $(".setupTitle").click(function(){

    $(this).next().slideToggle();

  });
```

or using your method of `.parent()` you need to use `.find()` not `.next()` because the element you are looking for is a child once you traverse back to the parent:

```
$(this).parent(".setupBlock").find(".setupData").slideToggle();
```

`.find()` looks for descendants while `.next()` looks for the next element

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `.next()`, you want `.find()`:

```
$(".setupTitle").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".setupBlock").find(".setupData").slideToggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/snLosfyy/)**

First you go up the DOM to the parent with `$(this).parent(".setupBlock")`. Then the `.next()` element would be the next sibling `<div class="setupBlock">` which you don't want. By using `.find(".setupData")` you stay within the div, and search down within it to find the relative `.setupData` div.

Answer (score 0):

In your code only have to find to parent's result:

```
 $(".setupTitle").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().find(".setupData").slideToggle();
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How's this different from my answer?